# Conditionally displaying/hiding parts of document using macros

Tags: macros, conditionals

I'm currently using the following approach to conditionally display/hide parts of my document:

```
% PREAMBLE

\def\MyVersion{1}

% BODY

\ifnum\MyVersion=1
This is version one.
% possibly other paragraphs, math blocks, tables, figures, etc
\fi

\ifnum\MyVersion=2
This is version two.
% possibly other paragraphs, math blocks, tables, figures, etc
\fi
```

To tidy up a bit, I tried to define macros for the `\ifnum` and `\fi` statements in the preamble:

```
\def\StartVersionOne{\ifnum\MyVersion=1}
\def\StopVersionOne{\fi}
\def\StartVersionTwo{\ifnum\MyVersion=2}
\def\StopVersionTwo{\fi}
```

However, this produces the following error:

```
! Incomplete \ifnum; all text was ignored after line ...
```

Strangely, everything works if I only use the `\StartXXX` macros and not the `\StopXXX` macros.
Can anyone explain what is going on? Am I defining the macros wrongly for `\fi`?

Comment: For LaTeX, you can use the `comment` package. For ConTeXt, you can use [Modes](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modes). Perhaps you can look at the implementation of these solution to see how to implement the same in plain TeX.

Comment: See also [this Q&A](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5076/2975) which discusses something very similar, just for different languages instead of versions.

Comment: Take a look at this question and answer: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10069/how-to-multiply-compile-according-to-selected-tags/10075#10075] which (I think) does what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
\def\StopVersionOne{\fi}
```

with

```
\let\StopVersionOne=\fi
```

Then it should work. Explanation: TeX scans ahead for finding a `\fi` that matches the `\ifnum`, but it scans *without expanding* if the test turns out false, so with `\def` it doesn't find the `\fi`.

If in any case you're using *nested* conditionals, please read Martin's answer (and the comments to my answer).

Comment: No, that's not enough in the general case. See my answer.

Comment: @Martin: I'm not exactly sure what you mean; _in the context of the OP_ my answer should work.

Comment: The if-switches are not matched, e.g.: `\iffalse \StartVersionOne \StopVersionOne \fi` breaks because 
`\StartVersionOne` is not expanded. A simple solution works if there are no other conditionals, but as soon there are one it breaks.

Comment: @Martin: I see no `\iffalse` or `\iftrue` in the OP. (I see them in your answer, but I don't think they're needed to solve the OP's problem. And I do see that my answer breaks for nested conditionals; I'll add that to my answer.)

Comment: Fun-fact: I spent the last three hours to make my new `collcell` package to work with conditionals in tabular cells, without much success. Especially because the first cell token is expanded before I can read it and therefore in a last but empty cell the `\\ ` is expanded, which contains some `\iffalse{\fi\ifnum0\`}\fi` which really freaks my parser out! :-)

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't work because the `\StopVersionOne` is never expanded when it is in the `\else` path and therefore the containing `\fi` is never seen by TeX.
Inside an `false` path TeX skips ahead without expanding macros until it finds one which is identical to `\fi`, e.g. `\fi` itself or a macro which was `\let` to it. However, other including `\if...` and their closing `\fi` are also counted.

In order for this to work you need to `\let` these macros to `\iffalse`/`\iftrue` and `\fi` respectively, e.g. everytime you change `\MyVersion` you `\let` the corresponding macro to `\iftrue` and all others to `\iffalse`. All `\Stop...` macros are `\let` to `\fi.

However this still doesn't work if your text includes unmatch `\if..`/`\fi`s.

Another way to do it is the `comments` package which skips everything verbatim to avoid these issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you count your versions 1,2,3,.. then use `\ifcase`

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\def\MyVersion{1}
\begin{document}

\ifcase\MyVersion\or
This is version one.
% possibly other paragraphs, math blocks, tables, figures, etc
\or
This is version two.
% possibly other paragraphs, math blocks, tables, figures, etc
\fi

\end{document}
```