# Creating a macro that conditionally turns on an \iffalse and \fi

Tags: macros, conditionals

I'd like to construct a conditional `\iffalse` and `\fi`.
Specifically, I'd like to define a counter and a macro such that if the counter set to one,the macro would either set an `\iffalse`, if the argument to the macro were "on", or a `\fi`, if the argument to the macro were "off".    Similar questions have been asked in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11258/conditionally-displaying-hiding-parts-of-document-using-macros) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10069/how-to-multiply-compile-according-to-selected-tags/10075#10075]) but both involve more complicated constructions than my simple one.

In the code below, I define a counter `Skip` and a macro `\mySkip` which, if correctly defined, would, if `\Skip` were set to `1`, would return `\iffalse` in response to the line `\mySkip{on}` and `\fi` in response to the line `\mySkip{off}`.   If `\Skip` were set to `0`, the macro would be ignored.     In this way, I could alter one line of my code, and thus display or not display large sections of text.

The macro, instead of *suppressing* the text between `\mySkip{on}` and `\mySkip{off}` merely *postpones* printing the text between `\mySkip{on}` and `\mySkip{off}` until after the `\mySkip{\off}`.    Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks for any advice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\makeatother
\newif\ifstrcmp
\makeatletter
\def\isstrcmp#1#2{
        \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{#1}{#2}=0
                \strcmptrue
        \else
                \strcmpfalse
        \fi
}
\makeatother
\newcounter{Skip}
\def\mySkip#1{\ifthenelse{\theSkip=1}{
        \isstrcmp{#1}{on}
        \ifstrcmp
            \iffalse
        \else
            \fi
            Text should resume after this\\
        \fi
        }{
        }}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{Skip}{1}
\mySkip{on}
This line should be skipped because it's between an ``iffalse'' and a ``fi''\\
In fact it's ``postponed" till immediately after the macro is ``closed"\\ \\
\mySkip{off}
This is the first line after the macro has been closed
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you seen `comment.sty`? It offers a more user-friendly interface than having to fiddle with counters.

Comment: Is switching from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX an option for you?

Comment: Please do not use `minimal` for examples.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to emulate conditionals (`\iftrue`, `\iffalse`, `\else`, `\fi`) by macros, because TeX's scanning for `\else` and `\fi` does *not* involve macro expansion. The conditional commands can only be assigned to other names (via `\let`). The starting conditional can be hidden inside macros as long as it is not inside the branch of another conditional.

Example for a macro setting the counter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{Skip}% default is zero

\newcommand*{\mySkipOn}{%
  \setcounter{Skip}{1}%
  \iffalse
}
\newcommand*{\mySkipOff}{%
  \setcounter{Skip}{0}%
  \iftrue
}
\let\mySkipEnd=\fi

\begin{document}
\mySkipOn
This line should be skipped because it's between an \verb|\iffalse\verb|
and \verb|\fi|.\\
\mySkipEnd
This is the first line after the macro has been closed.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Caution: `\mySkipOn`/`\mySkipOff` cannot be nested, because TeX will not recognize macros as conditionals, when it ignores the token of a conditional branch, which is not selected.

Example for a macro using a counter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{Skip}% default is zero

\newcommand*{\mySkipBegin}{%
  \ifnum\value{Skip}=1 %
    \csname iffalse\expandafter\endcsname
  \else
    \csname iftrue\expandafter\endcsname
  \fi
}
\let\mySkipEnd=\fi

\begin{document}
\setcounter{Skip}{1}
\mySkipBegin
This line should be skipped because it's between an \verb|\iffalse\verb|
and \verb|\fi|.\\
\mySkipEnd
This is the first line after the macro has been closed.
\end{document}
```

Again `\mySkipBegin` should not appear inside other conditional branches. Its definition shows, how unmatched conditionals can be hidden via `\csname` inside outer branches. The `\expandafter` commands ends the outer conditional branches, leaving `\iftrue` or `\iffalse` at the end.

Comment: If I understood your answer correctly, the actions of `\mySkipOn` and `\mySkipOn` are not conditional on the value of `Skip`. Is this correct?

Comment: @Mico You are right, I have now added an example the other way round. But I do not know, what the purpose of the counter is. Two values (0 and 1) can be easily expressed by a simple boolean switch defined by `\newif`.

Answer (score 0):

Delimited arguments might be your friends.

Ulrich

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\makeatletter
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.........................................................................
%% \CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                  {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                    argument which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                  {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                    argument which is to be checked is not empty>}%
\newcommand\@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@firstoftwo\expandafter\@secondoftwo\expandafter}\string
  }\@firstoftwo
}%
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument contains no exclamation-mark on top-brace-level:
%%.........................................................................
%% \CheckWhetherNoExclamationMark{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                  {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                    argument which is to be checked does not contain !>}%
%%                  {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                    argument which is to be checked does contain !>}%
\newcommand\@RemoveToExclamationMark{}%
\long\def\@RemoveToExclamationMark#1!{}%
\newcommand\@CheckWhetherNoExclamationMark[1]{%
  \expandafter\@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\@RemoveToExclamationMark#1!}%
}%
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \mySkip{ON/TRUE/1} AND Skip = 1 -> Things until next \mySkip{...}
%%                                    within the same brace-level 
%%                                    will be skkipped.
%% !!The material to be skipped must not contain \outer tokens.!!
%%.........................................................................
\newcommand\@mySkipFork{}%
\long\def\@mySkipFork#1!!ON!TRUE!1!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
\newcommand\mySkip[1]{%
  \ifnum\number\value{Skip}=1 %
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \else
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \fi
  {%
    \@CheckWhetherNoExclamationMark{#1}{%
      \uppercase{%
        \@mySkipFork
        !!#1!TRUE!1!{\removeToNextMySkip}%<-ON
        !!ON!#1!1!{\removeToNextMySkip}%<-TRUE
        !!ON!TRUE!#1!{\removeToNextMySkip}%<-1
        !!ON!TRUE!1!{}%<-ELSE
        !!!!%
      }%
    }{}%<-ELSE
  }%
  \ignorespaces
}%
%
\newcommand\removeToNextMySkip{}%
\long\def\removeToNextMySkip#1\mySkip#2{\ignorespaces}%
%
\newcounter{Skip}%
%
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\setcounter{Skip}{1}
This is the first phrase that should definitely not be skipped.
\mySkip{oN}
This phrase should probably be skipped.
\mySkip{off}
This is the second phrase that should definitely not be skipped.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following approach allows skipping of `\outer` tokens and skipping things like instances of the verbatim environment as well.  Be aware that you cannot hide `\mySkip{...}` within other macros or within macros' arguments and that `\mySkip` should not be "renamed" (via `\let`).

Matching `\mySkip{...}`-pairs must not come from macro-expansion but they must occur within the same .tex-input-file.

This time the code comes without any `\if`..-switches within the macro code.

Instead of wasting a `\count`-register for the Skip-counter, a simple
macro `\Skipflag` is invented. If that is not defined to expand to the
phrase "1", nothing will be skipped.

Ulrich

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\makeatletter
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.........................................................................
%% \CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                  {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                    argument which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                  {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                    argument which is to be checked is not empty>}%
\newcommand\@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@firstoftwo\expandafter\@secondoftwo\expandafter}\string
  }\@firstoftwo
}%
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument contains no exclamation-mark on top-brace-level:
%%.........................................................................
%% \CheckWhetherNoExclamationMark{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                  {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                    argument which is to be checked does not contain !>}%
%%                  {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                    argument which is to be checked does contain !>}%
\newcommand\@RemoveToExclamationMark{}%
\long\def\@RemoveToExclamationMark#1!{}%
\newcommand\@CheckWhetherNoExclamationMark[1]{%
  \expandafter\@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\@RemoveToExclamationMark#1!}%
}%
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \mySkip{ON/TRUE/1} AND \Skipflag = 1 -> Things until next \mySkip{...}
%%                                         will be skkipped.
%%.........................................................................
\newcommand\@mySkipFork{}%
\long\def\@mySkipFork#1!!1.ON!1.TRUE!1.1!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
\newcommand\mySkip[1]{%
  \expandafter\@mySkip\expandafter{\number0\Skipflag.#1}%
}%
\newcommand\@mySkip[1]{%
    \@CheckWhetherNoExclamationMark{#1}{%
      \uppercase{%
        \@mySkipFork
        !!#1!1.TRUE!1.1!{\removeToNextMySkip}%<-ON
        !!1.ON!#1!1.1!{\removeToNextMySkip}%<-TRUE
        !!1.ON!1.TRUE!#1!{\removeToNextMySkip}%<-1
        !!1.ON!1.TRUE!1.1!{}%<-ELSE
        !!!!%
      }%
    }{}%<-ELSE
  \ignorespaces
}%
%
\newcommand\removeToNextMySkip{%
  \begingroup
  \let\do\@makeother
  \dospecials
  \@removeToNextMySkip
}%
\begingroup
\newcommand\@removeToNextMySkip{%
   \endgroup
   \begingroup
   \newcommand\@removeToNextMySkip[1]{%
     \endgroup
     \long\def\@removeToNextMySkip####1##1{%
       \endgroup\@firstoftwo{\ignorespaces}%
     }%
   }%
   \let\do\@makeother
   \dospecials
   \catcode`\{=1 %
   \catcode`\}=2 %
   \@removeToNextMySkip%
}%
\@removeToNextMySkip{\mySkip}%
%
\makeatother

\outer\def\outerphrase{%
  This phrase comes from an outer-deffed token and it should
  probably be skipped as well. %
}%


\begin{document}
\newcommand\Skipflag{1}%
%\renewcommand\Skipflag{0}%
This is the first phrase that should definitely not be skipped.
\mySkip{oN}
This phrase should probably be skipped.
\outerphrase
\begin{verbatim}
And this is some verbatim stuff that also should probably be skipped.
\end{verbatim}
\mySkip{off}
This is the second phrase that should definitely not be skipped.
\end{document}
```